# SCVMM: A Hardware Management error has occurred trying to contact server %servername%:a:DestinationUnreachable

Tags: hyper-v

Today we found our host status is "Needs Attention".
We have upgraded the WMF 3.0.

And to check the health status and it reports the following error:

> A Hardware Management error has occurred trying to contact server
>   iwwbgc8.dir.slb.com :a:DestinationUnreachable :The WS-Management
>   service cannot process the request. The service cannot find the
>   resource identified by the resource URI and selectors. .
>
> Check that WinRM is installed and running on server
>   iwwbgc8.dir.slb.com. For more information use the command "winrm
>   helpmsg hresult".
>
> ID: 2927 Details: Unknown error (0x8033803b)

Following the post: [How to Interpret Job Failures in VMM](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8827.how-to-interpret-job-failures-in-vmm.aspx) and [How to troubleshoot the “Needs Attention” and “Not Responding” host status in System Center 2012 Virtual Machine Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2742246/en-us)
But the error is still there.
And there does some performance issue in events but by following the post [How to manually rebuild Performance Counters for Windows Server 2008 64bit or Windows Server 2008 R2 systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2554336/en-us), the performance counter can't not be fixed.

### Error:

> 1. Installing the performance counter strings for service .NET Data Provider for Oracle (_) failed. The first DWORD in the Data section
>      contains the error code.
> 2. Cannot repair performance counters for .NET Data Provider for Oracle service. Reinstall the performance counters manually using the
>      LODCTR tool.
> 3. Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND
>      TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in
>      namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot
>      be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.
> 4. Unable to read Server Queue performance data from the Server service. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the
>      status code, the second four bytes contains the IOSB.Status and the
>      next four bytes contains the IOSB.Information.

Any idea bout it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later we found the issue is caused by the WMF 3.0 upgrade.

We follow the post [Managing Hyper-V hosts using Virtual Machine Manager fails with Error: 0x8033803b after installing WMF 3.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2795043/en-us) and apply the hotfix.

The hotfix (Windows6.1-KB2781512-x64) is applied but the issue still exists.

At last I select the solution to uninstall the WMF 3.0.

And the issue is fixed at last.